# Cannot send xmlhttpsrequest from a javascript function

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have a javscript function which works on form submit

```
function TxEncrypt(event)
{ //perform encryption of token data, then submit the form like normal

    //obtain public key and initial JSEncrypt object
    var txPubKey = txJ$(".zwitch_encryptionkey").val();
    var txEncrypter = new JSEncrypt();
    txEncrypter.setPublicKey(txPubKey);

    //get Data and encrypt it
    var txData = '{}';
    var txCryptData = '';
    if(txJ$(".zwitch_data").length > 1)
    { //if there are more than one element with this class, convert it to json string
        txData = txJ$(".zwitch_data").serializeObject();
        txCryptData = txEncrypter.encrypt(JSON.stringify(txData));
    }
    else
    {   //else, just encrypt the value
        txData = txJ$(".zwitch_data").val();
        txCryptData = txEncrypter.encrypt(txData);
    }


    dataString = txCryptData; // array?
    var cipher=dataString;
                if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
                      {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
                         xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
                      }
                else
                      {// code for IE6, IE5
                          xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
                      }

                xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
                      {
                             if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
                            {               
                            result=xmlhttp.responseText;
                            alert(result);
                            }
                      }     

                xmlhttp.open("POST","tokenize.php?cipher="+cipher,true);
                xmlhttp.send();
}
```

On submit , the function is working fine.I can alert value of cipher.

The php on which the POST is done is

```
  $cipher = $_REQUEST['cipher'];
  echo $cipher;
```

When I tried with the xmlhttprequest part alone,it worked.But when I place inside the function its not working.Whats wrong here?

Comment: I'm sorry, but why do you mark your question with `jquery` tag yet doesn't use its useful `$.ajax` component?

Comment: Prevent default behaviour of submiting FORM, then submit it inside success callback of the ajax request

Comment: @A.Wolff Thank you.Im new to this.Can u show me an example for what you have suggested

Comment: @PiyaSharma @A.Wolff meant to do this `event.preventDefault()` after `function TxEncrypt(event) {`. It will prevent default behaviour of the form.